# Insert php multiple data into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have 1000+ customers. I require customer report.

Here `debit` = `potato + onion + ginger`. `Credit` is `commission`.`Balance` will be updated every time. It will be `balance - debit`  and `balance + credit` alternatively.

`Grocery` data report is as: Data is filled through php form with `mysql_fetch_array` query. Here few customers are as sample. and few data fields.

```
id   cus_id    cus_name   potato   onion   ginger  debit   credit   balance
1    12        munna      10       25      28      63      0        37
2    16        anil       24       56      84      164     0        136
3    34        palash     17       47      51      115     0        85
4    45        dimpy      35       64      39      138     0        112
```

Table `grocery` before and after entering new data:

```
id   cus_id    cus_name   potato   onion   ginger  debit   credit   balance

1    12        munna      10       25      28      63      0        37
2    16        anil       24       56      84      164     0        136
3    34        palash     17       47      51      115     0        85
4    45        dimpy      35       64      39      138     0        112

5    12        munna      0        0       0       0       6        43
6    16        anil       0        0       0       0       16       152
7    34        palash     0        0       0       0       12       97
8    45        dimpy      0        0       0       0       14       126
```

My problem is :

I am unable to update `balance` column, `cus_name` wise and `cus_id` wise and insert all data into mysql database. Suggest me with mysql query.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Where does *credit* information derive? From users via PHP form? Also, is your second data table the *current* result or *desired* result? I am not understanding what works and doesn't and what you need.

Comment: Credit information come from php form.  I want to update  `balance column`, cus_name wise and cus_id wise and insert all data into mysql database

Comment: So second table is **three** PHP form data appends, showing how you want *balance* to render? Why are you tracking balance without a timestamp?

Comment: Second table with `two` php data. one from customer. second comes from admin where commission will be given as credit to all customers at once. My query should be as admin  to update balance column, cus_name wise and cus_id wise and insert all data into mysql database